# When I use ggplotly function in plotly , why does the text annotation lost?

Tags: ggplot2, plotly

Why does my text information lost after use ggplotly function to draw the ggplot obeject？
Could anyone tell me how to add the axis text information to the point?My code list here.

```
data <- data.frame(x=c(1,3,4,6),y=c(2,5,9,6),z=c(1,1,2,2))
data
ggplot(data,aes(x,y,label=x))+geom_point()+geom_text()+facet_grid(z~.,scales="free_y")
ggplotly()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the text info through aes within geom_point

```
ggplot(data,aes(x,y,label=x))+geom_point(aes(text=x))+geom_text()+facet_grid(z~.,scales="free_y")
ggplotly()

ggplot(data,aes(x,y,label=x))+geom_point(aes(text=paste("X axis=", x, "and Y axis=", y))) +geom_text()+facet_grid(z~.,scales="free_y")
ggplotly()
```